# Как отключить выделение по умолчанию в tkintertable?

Tags: python, tkinter

С python знаком немного, особенно с tkinter. Мне нужна чистая таблица, но по молчанию на ней выделена определенная строка, из за чего портится эстетический вид и непонятно какого цвета строка.
Желательно вообще убрать возможность выделения таблицы.
Вот так это выглядит, первая строка выделена, и ячейка (1,1) выделена особым образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал и `read_only=True` в создании таблицы, но то же самое.

Код самый простой, но на всякий случай приложу:

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
class createTable(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.F = tk.Frame(self)
        self.F.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.table = TableCanvas(self.F,rows=30,cols=30)
        self.table.createTableFrame()\
        
app = createTable() 
app.master.title('Sample Table') 
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Определенно надо использовать `focus_set()`, но к какому-то другому виджету. Мб к окну попробовать

Comment: @handowl дело в том что, оно выделено даже тогда, когда фокус не на виджете таблице

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убрать выделение можно с помощью метода `setSelectedRow` с параметром -1:

> To deselect/not select any row, you can use `table.setSelectedRow(-1)`

Источник: [Usage - Selecting rows](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable/wiki/Usage#selecting-rows)

Пример:

```
def createWidgets(self):
    self.table = TableCanvas(self.F,rows=30,cols=30)
    self.table.setSelectedRow(-1)
    self.table.createTableFrame()
```

[image: Скриншот]